# How do I set environmental variables in my client-side code?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I need to set a different key depending on if we are in development or production. What is a good way to do this in client-side which has no inherent runtime environment?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a build-script? When you minimize your code, you also swap the variable value from development to production.

Comment: By "no inherent runtime environment", do you also mean that it might be executed in an interpreter shell versus deployed on a website?

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson I think this might be the best route, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: On the client side you have a "window" object...maybe you can key off of that (?)

Answer (score 4):

One way is to inject an environment variable from the server into the global namespace on the client.

For example, if you were doing this in PHP:

```
<script>
    var env = <?php echo $your_env_variable; ?>; // globally accessible variable
</script>
```

Now you can access that environment variable from any javascript files that are executed after that script tag.

In node you would do the same thing, but with templating (for example Jade):

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    var env = passedInEnvVar
```

Answer (score 2):

In nodejs the "official" way to specify the environment is to use "NODE_ENV". Since you did not mention the framework that you are using for serving the HTML content, I will use expressjs for my answer.

You can simply do this in your view template (I am using EJS)

```
  var key = '<%= keys[process.env.NODE_ENV] %>'
```

You will need to prepare a set of keys corresponding to each environment

```
var keys = {
  'development': 'dev-key',
  'production': 'prod-key'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just load a different script? You can create the script dynamically based on a GET parameter e.g. http://example.org/script.js?development=1, and then change the contents of the code based on that parameter with a server-side language like PHP.

You can also use rewrite rules on your web server to make it look cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

A `<meta name='environment' content='<%= yourVariable %>' />` in the head of the page works well to (ejs sample, but you get the idea).

This method will help you keep a more strict Content-Security-Policy (no `inline-script`), and you won't have to add a route in your server to get the required value.